# R .Library and libpaths() returns different result

Tags: r, system

libpaths() returns valid result:

```
"D:/R/R-3.3.3/library"
```

but .Library returns a result not valid:

```
"D:/R/R-33~1.3/library"
```

Is this expected or not?

Comment: [`?.libPaths`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/libPaths.html) (which discussed both `.Library` and what I'm inferring you mean as `.libPaths()`, since I don't have `libpaths` in my R-3.5.3). That path may look not-valid, but occasionally on windows some paths need to be encoded to an 8-char mapping of sorts. That's what that looks like to me (though my win10 system does not exhibit the same symptom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a Mac I also get two different paths:

```r
.Library
# [1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library"

.libPaths()
# [1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library"
```

The docs have this to say about `.Library` (emphasis mine):

> .Library is a character string giving the location of the **default library**, the ‘library’ subdirectory of R_HOME.

And this about `.libPaths()` (emphasis mine):

> .libPaths is used for getting or setting **the library trees that R knows about** (and hence uses when looking for packages).

In fact, both paths point to the same directory via different routes because the `Resources` in the first path is an alias pointing to the same `Resources` in the second path. The main difference is that `Versions` in the second path contains multiple directories for different versions (the so-called "library trees that R knows about"). Version 3.6 is currently my default library, which is why `.Library` also points to it. I assume the same logic applies to Windows.

Comment: First appreciated for your detailed answer, Are you sure these two path pointed to the same folder? In my win10 system I can't use the path .Library gives me and the system tell me that path not exists in win10 system

Comment: when I try to go into D:/R/R-33~1.3/library the system tells me windows couldn't find the path

Comment: @cloudscomputes yes, they definitely do. When I manually navigate to each library in the finder and copy the paths they are identical. Also, if I create a folder in one path it appears in the other as well. Maybe R for Windows doesn't know how to deal with shortcuts/aliases?

Answer (score 0):

They are supposed to be the same

However in windows you can't use .Library's value directly to locate the folder.

But when I create folder using either libpaths and .Library, the result located in the same folder~

Since I think this is helpful so I post my answer for my own question here.